# Repeated filesystems and mount points in df output

Tags: filesystems, mount, disk-usage

when I type `df -h` to see the storage of my system the following is the result

```
root@kch-rsp:/home/pi# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs           13G  2.4G   10G  20% /
/dev/root        13G  2.4G   10G  20% /
devtmpfs        215M     0  215M   0% /dev
tmpfs            44M  228K   44M   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            88M     0   88M   0% /run/shm
/dev/mmcblk0p5   60M  9.4M   50M  16% /boot
```

there are several questions about this result:

1. why are there multiple `tmpfs`? I know that this is a swap space but when I executed `swapon -s`, I only see one swap space.

   ```
   root@kch-rsp:/home/pi# swapon -s
   Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
   /var/swap                               file            102396  0       -1
   ```
2. the `rootfs` and `/dev/root` looks like to be indicating the same thing but why express them as these two entries?

Comment: do `findmnt` for more info.

Comment: I do not see how tmpfs and swap space are related? The swap space is on a partition normally, but without a filesystem, and not mounted.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel then from my output, why are there three `tmpfs`? does it mean that there are three tmpfs swap files that are mounted to three different directories?

Comment: There is some relation in that the content of a tmpfs can get written to swap space like other data, which is not possible for the simpler ramfs.

Comment: It means there are three tmpfs file systems mounted into three directories. That has nothing to do with which swap files exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is already [a good answer in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152357/multiple-filesystems-in-df#comment248520_152357) by [Volker Siegel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/63775/volker-siegel) related to `tmpfs`:

> It means there are three tmpfs file systems mounted into three directories. That has nothing to do with which swap files exist.

I can add a reference explaining the `rootfs` issue.

```
ramfs, rootfs and initramfs
October 17, 2005
Rob Landley 
=============================
...
What is rootfs?
---------------
Rootfs is a special instance of ramfs (or tmpfs, if that's enabled), which is
always present in 2.6 systems.  You can't unmount rootfs for approximately the
same reason you can't kill the init process; ...

Most systems just mount another filesystem over rootfs and ignore it.  The
amount of space an empty instance of ramfs takes up is tiny.
...
```

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt

Take a look at the "What is initramfs?" section in the same document to get some information on how the system uses `rootfs`.

Comment: But how do I distinguish which tmpfs is which? Sometimes they mean the same actual tmpfs. When you create a file in one of them, the USED space increases in another.